# Backward Propagation and Hinge Loss

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, svm, loss-function

I plan to write a function which will output the derivative of a hinge loss w.r.t the ground truth. I consider the function as following from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244095/hinge-loss-function-gradient-w-r-t-input-prediction)
[image]
whereas Y(the first parameter)is the prediction and Y. (the second parameter) is the ground truth.

During calculating backward loss, what I understand is, I need to calculate the derivative of the above loss w.r.t the second parameter, right? 
In that case, will the code be like following:

```
function dLdX = backwardLoss1( this, Y, T )
            % backwardLoss    Back propagate the derivative of the loss
            % function
            %
            % Syntax:
            %   dLdX = layer.backwardLoss( Y, T );
            %
            % Image Inputs:
            %   Y   Predictions made by network, 1-by-1-by-numClasses-by-numObs
            %   T   Targets (actual values), 1-by-1-by-numClasses-by-numObs
            %
            % Vector Inputs:
            %   Y   Predictions made by network,  numClasses-by-numObs-by-seqLength
            %   T   Targets (actual values),  numClasses-by-numObs-by-seqLength
          if(Y*T<1)
                dLdX=-T/size(Y);
           else
                dLdX=0;
            end         
        end
```

But following this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/gradient-of-hinge-loss), it's displaying the calculation of the derivative w.r.t the parameters which make me confuse that should I need to output the loss w.rt the weights as well as w.r.t to the ground truth?
I am looking for your suggestions in this regard.
thanks,

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve here? If you want to differentiate with respect to the ground truth, then your approach is correct. However, if you want to train a neural network using this loss, you want to back-propagate the loss to update  the network weights, and in that case you will need derivatives with respect to the weights.

Comment: @zfabian: thanks for your response. Yes, my goal is to train the network using the loss. And according to you, the backwardLoss1()  would then return dLdX and dLdW as well, right? In that case, dLdX would be -T/size(Y) if Y*T<1 and dLdW would be -yx if yx.w<1 otherwise dLdW would be zero(if I get it correctly, according to the second refernce I mentioned in my post). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the reference is correct if you are training a binary classifier.

Comment: @zfabian: thank you. I am working with binary classification at present and later I would focus on multiclass classification. Now, I'm getting the thing. If this is the scenario, what is xi during calculating dLdW? What I am understanding from reference 2 is, y is the ground truth of observation will be multiplied by the dot product of the output of the last layer. Am I getting it correctly? Then is x1 the feature sets of the first observation when i=1?